# how can i to DECLARE a mysql list variable

Tags: mysql, variables

in a TRIGGER i must be check two fields with a SELECT result 
is possible to declare a local variable as array list to storing a SELECT result such as :

```
SELECT lid FROM lang WHERE state=1 ;
```

this SELECT statement return me always more than one result
if is possible to definition it and what is the variable type for a list ?

Comment: That would not be the MySQL way of implementing this logic.  I would actually recommend that you ask another question with more information about what you want the trigger to really do.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your goal.

But just a guess. You don't need any variable but you can use `IN` condition:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1434/1

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE lang_id IN (SELECT lid FROM lang WHERE state=1 )
```